# Override method, why can't I referenciate new own methods?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I don't understand this:

```
OnGlobalLayoutListener listener = new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
         System.out.println("I am override a method");
    }

    public void hello(){
         System.out.println("This is a new method");
    }
};

//listener.hello(); Why I cannot do it?
```

Without this I can do it:

```
new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
             System.out.println("I am override a method");
        }

        public void hello(){
             System.out.println("This is a new method");
        }
    }.hello();
```

Why in the first case cannot I invoke the method hello() and the second case I can do it?

Comment: Same problem as in

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800678/can-i-access-new-methods-in-anonymous-inner-class-with-some-syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a new anonymous type, with a new method called `hello`.

You can call `hello` on the expression `new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { }` because the type of that expression *is* your new anonymous type.

You *can't* call `hello` on `listener` because the compile-time type of `listener` is `OnGlobalLayoutListener`, which doesn't have a `hello` method.

If you want to add extra methods, I would personally suggest you create a new nested class within your current class. You *can* declare a new named class right within a method, but I wouldn't advise it, just in terms of the clutter it creates.

Note that the overriding of `onGlobalLayout` is completely irrelevant to the question. You'd see the same thing if you tried writing:

```
new Object {
    public void hello() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, you instantiate an object by creating an [anonymous inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html), but the way you reference the `hello()`method differs:

In the first case, you assign the instantiated class to a reference of the `OnGlobalLayoutListener` *interface*. The problem is that the interface has not declared the `hello()` method, so it cannot be called. However, there is no problem if you try calling the `onGlobalLayout()`.

In the second case, the `hello()` method is accessible, because you call it on reference of the *class* that was just instantiated. In contrast to the interface, the class has two methods, the overriden `onGlobalLayout()` and the requested `hello()` method.